# How does CefSharp inject JS into new pages opened in Windows.open

Tags: c#, cefsharp, window.open

My Winform application uses `CefSharp`,
When I open `page1.html` in `CefSharp`,
the `page1.html` is not my own page and I have no control over the code of this page.
The `page1.html` code looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is page 111
        <script language=javascript>
            var toUrl="http://localhost/KintechToGica22/page2.html";
            window.open(toUrl,'openTest2','');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can inject JS into `page1.html` with the following c# code

```cs
//ChromiumWebBrowser browser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\my.js");
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(text);
```

I use `window.open` in `pag1.html` to open a page `page2.html`,
The `page2.html` code looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>page2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is Page 222
    </body>
</html>
```

But how do I control `page2.html`,
I want to do something with `page2.html` injection JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.open` call will create a new popup. You can get load events for popups (and main browser) by implementing [LoadHandler](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/101.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_LoadHandler.htm).

A basic example would look something like:

```cs
public class CustomLoadHandler : CefSharp.Handler.LoadHandler
{
    protected override void OnFrameLoadStart(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, FrameLoadStartEventArgs args)
    {
        // Execute script before DOM has started loading
        // window.open will create a new popup, check IsPopup = true
        // Add any additional checks like comparing the URL that meet your requirements 
        // Execute your script here on in OnFrameLoadEnd. Not both
        if (args.Browser.IsPopup && args.Frame.Url.EndsWith("page2.html"))
        {
            string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\my.js");
            args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
        }
        base.OnFrameLoadStart(chromiumWebBrowser, args);
    }

    protected override void OnFrameLoadEnd(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
    {
        // Execute script before DOM has started loading
        // window.open will create a new popup, check IsPopup = true
        // Add any additional checks like comparing the URL that meet your requirements
        // Execute your script here on in OnFrameLoadStart. Not both
        if (args.Browser.IsPopup && args.Frame.Url.EndsWith("page2.html"))
        {
            string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\my.js");
            args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
        }

        base.OnFrameLoadEnd(chromiumWebBrowser, args);
    }
}

chromiumWebBrowser.LoadHandler = new CustomLoadHandler();
```